# Grocery CRUD Callback

Tags: php, codeigniter, crud, callback

Estou precisando setar uma mensagem para o usuário, após a validação de uma função callback, porém, não entro nada referente. Tem uma mensagem genérica que serve para o formulário inteiro, eu quero por campos.

Tentei com `form_validation->set_message`, porém não funcionou.

Agradeço se alguém souber como fazer pra exibir uma mensagem personalizada, vinda de uma função de callback.

Comment: Robson, mostre o código que você esta usando e como esta usando o Grocery Crud para que possamos te ajudar.

Comment: Olá, @RafaelAcioly! Então, por fim eu desisti do Grocery Crud. Estava me dando mais trabalho do que se eu fosse fazer na mão. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Um exemplo:

```
 /** CHAMADA REGRA**/
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('campo', 'Label Campo', 'required', ['nome_regra', [$Objeto, 'nome_funcao_valida']]], 
            ['required' => 'Campo obrigatorio.']);


/** FUNCAO QUE VALIDA **/
function nome_funcao_valida($valor)
    {
     if(CONDICAO)
          return true;
    else
    {
       $this->form_validation->set_message('nome_regra', 'A {field} não confere');
                return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá, yathal! Então, tentei dessa forma, mas não deu certo também. Por fim, desisti e fiz tudo na mão. Valeu!